# AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies behaves differently between servers

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I'm using `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` to discover types, but the same build fails to discover them in one server. Both servers have the same build from the web app installed!

How can this happen?

Comment: It will look for assemblies in the bin folder plus the probing paths; if they are different (web.config setting or different files deployed), you get different results.

Comment: @RicardoPeres: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` provides you with a list of assemblies currently loaded into your appdomain. No additional assemblies are loaded as a result of calling that method.

Comment: Of course... that is obvious.

Comment: @RicardoPeres they have the same settings and the deploy is the same. This is strange.

Comment: I also have problems with Type.GetCustomAttributes in the same server.

Comment: And both servers do have the same configuration, same .net framework,etc?

Comment: The .NET framework versions is the same (4.7.02053). The configuration, as far as I know, is also the same.